# linkbutton or button onClick not fireing inside gridview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hi i have a gridview in my asp.net webpage that is bounded after a user selects 3 dropdown list.
dropdown list's auto postbacks are set true , now my problem is when i put a button , imagebutton or linkbutton in my gridview ItemTemplate  the onclick event dosent fire !
here is my code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   Width="90%" Height="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" style="margin:20px; vertical-align:top;"  PageSize="10" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="WFStudentID" ShowHeader="true" BorderWidth="1px">

        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField  ShowHeader="true">
            <ItemTemplate >
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" ForeColor="Silver" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Silver" Font-Size="Medium"  Text='<%# Bind("Family") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" ForeColor="Silver" Font-Size="Medium" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("WFStudentFilePath") %>' runat="server">دانلود</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" ForeColor="Silver" Font-Size="Medium"  Text='<%# Bind("WFStudentDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Button ID="Deny" Text="deny"  OnClick="Deny_Click1"       runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="accept" OnClick="accept_Click"  runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="des" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" Width="200px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>  



protected void Deny_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out the answer here?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11455262/382214

Comment: Just to double check... have you put a breakpoint at the very top of `Deny_Click1`. You're swallowing potencial exceptions so maybe the problem is that there is an exception but you didn't realize about it.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi i put Response.redirect("home.aspx") it did not fire!!

Comment: @ewitkows thats not my problem..

Comment: Remove the Onclick event on your button and set the commandname and argument there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this::

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/how-to-handle-click-event-of-linkbutton.html

verify your code like this

Answer (score 2):

It is probably firing, but it will throw an exception (which your catch block ignores). The exception is because of this line:

> LinkButton Link = (LinkButton)sender;

The sender is a Button, not a LinkButton, so the cast is not valid and an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons inside GridView do not respond to direct events. They have to go through GridView's RowCommand event implementation. I've seen that you have implemented `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"`. So now you need make following change to image button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="accept"  runat="server" CommandName="Accept" />
```

Now look for "Accept" command name in your `GridView1_RowCommand` event handler.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
  {
    // Your code goes here
  }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't it hit GridView1_RowCommand event handler? Does it postback?

Comment: you are plain wrong. *Buttons inside GridView do not respond to direct events*? since when? please do not provide misinformation!

Comment: Thank you @naveen. Corrected myself.